# Automate runs of programs in Windows (Maybe using python or batch file)

Tags: python, batch-file

I need to run some python files over and over with different settings and different file names.

Here is an example of a task I need to do. This is for Linux, but I need to do the same thing in Windows. Is there a way to use python to be the caller and run other python scripts which are already set to work on STD I/O? Does python have a shell like this? I would rather do this than switch over to maintaining batch code on both Linux and Windows.

```
#!/bin/bash
#run scripts to generate and manipulate data

for ((i=1; i<=3 ; i++))
do
    randfuncgen.py -k 12 > randomvalues_$i.fitdata
    probe.py -k 12 < randomvalues_$i.fitdata > randomvalues_$i.walshdata
    std.py -m s < randomvalue_$i.walshdata > randomvalues_separate_std_$i.walshdata
    std.py -m a < randomvalue_$i.walshdata > randomvalues_all_std_$i.walshdata
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the [python `subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module) module to do exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Your code could look like

```
import subprocess
for i in range(3):
    subprocess.Popen(['-k', 12],                                  # args
                     -1,                                          # buffer_sie
                     'python randfuncgen.py',                     # executable
                     stdout=open("randomvalues_%i.fitdata"%i,'w') # output
                     )
    # Other such processes/executions
```

Answer (score 0):

Each one of your programs (randfuncgen.py, probe.py, std.py) would need to support outputting via sys.stdout.write('your output'), and inputting via sys.stdin.

You can take a look at the documentation on the subprocess module and the relevant section on "replacing the shell pipeline" here http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline

so for example:

```
import subprocess as sp
for counter in range(1,4):
    p1 = sp.Popen(['randfuncgen.py','-k','12',], stout=sp.PIPE)
    p2 = sp.Popen(['probe.py', '-k', '12'], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
    p3 = sp.Popen(['std.py', '-m', 's'], stdin=p2.stdout, stdout='randomvalues_separate_std_%d.walshdata'%counter)
    p4 = sp.Popen(['std.py', '-m', 'a'], stdin=p2.stdout, stdout='randomvalues_all_std_%d.walshdata'%counter)
```

You may have to do output from p2 as a file, as I'm not sure if the pipe is exhausted before p4 runs